# Xcode 3.2 iPhone dev - Can't download development application data anymore?

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

In the organizer of Xcode 3.1.x I used to be able to download the application data for an app in development (not installed thru itunes).  In Xcode 3.2 I don't see that option anywhere.  Am I missing something?

**Edit - One user provided an answer saying "look for the disclosure triangle". The disclosure triangles are missing and there isn't anything else to click on that responds to action.  It's like the feature has been removed entirely (although I'm sure it wasn't...maybe a bug in Xcode?)

Comment: The option is still there for me under Xcode 3.2.2, just as warrenm describes.  Note that this only works for your own applications that you've build and installed onto the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a reply from Apple, this is actually a bug in Xcode 3.2.  Here's what they said:

"This is a follow up to Bug ID# 7895047.  After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering. This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 7847465. The original bug number being used to track this duplicate issue can be found in the State column, in this format:  Duplicate/OrigBug#.

Thank you for submitting this bug report. We truly appreciate your assistance in helping us discover and isolate bugs.

Best Regards,

Patrick Collins
Apple Developer Connection 
Worldwide Developer Relations"

Answer (score 1):

Within Organizer, you should see the list of installed applications below the device info and the provisioning profile list. For each application, you can click on the disclosure triangle and then use the "Download" arrow on the right-hand side to retrieve the Application Data.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same bug today.  I was able to fix it within the organizer by deleting everything under the Projects & Sources section in the upper left corner of the organizer.  If you have transferred a large amount of data from the iphone in the past, you may have lots of files still sitting in the Projects & Sources section.  If you have deleted them from disk, you will see them show up in red text (indicating they have been deleted).  All I had to do was delete all of these files, restart xcode and disconnect/reconnect my iphone.  After that, the disclosure triangle showed up and all was right again with the organizer.  I was then able to download all my application data to my desktop.